# Removing Temp Table Skews Results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have two queries (which to me are identical with the exception of a temp table).  The 1st query with the temp table provides accurate and expected results.  The 2nd query w/o the temp table provides highly inflated counts.  Why is such?  They appear to be exactly the same query to me?

Can this query be constructed w/o a temp table and have accurate data returned?

**Query 1**

```
SELECT Distinct hacaNum as [HOV Number] , 
al.rstQMN,os.[STATE]
INTO  #helpertable     
FROM alpha al
LEFT OUTER JOIN foxtrot on  foxtrot.[foxtrot_ID] = al.[foxtrot_ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN charche as ch on ch.[rstQMN] = al.[rstQMN] AND ch.[foxtrot_ID] = al.[foxtrot_ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN zulu zl on zl.[SMI] = al.[SMI]
LEFT OUTER JOIN oscie os on os.[AI] = ch.[AI]
Where hacaNum = '88' 
 Order By hacaNum

SELECT [HOV Number],        
        Count([Tracking Number]) as Total
        ,State
From #helpertable
Group By [HOV Number],State
Order By [HOV Number]
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT Distinct hacaNum as [HOV Number] , 
[Alabama] = COUNT(case when os.[STATE] = 'AL' then 1 else 0 end)
,[MS] = Count(case when os.[STATE] = 'MS' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM alpha al
LEFT OUTER JOIN foxtrot on  foxtrot.[foxtrot_ID] = al.[foxtrot_ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN charche as ch on ch.[rstQMN] = al.[rstQMN] AND ch.[foxtrot_ID] = al.[foxtrot_ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN zulu zl on zl.[SMI] = al.[SMI]
LEFT OUTER JOIN oscie os on os.[AI] = ch.[AI]
Where hacaNum = '88' 
Group By hacaNum
 Order By hacaNum
```

**EDIT**
For clarification - I am needing a way to get a count by state breakdown for Alabama and MS.  (the other states do not matter).  When I attempt to get counts like in my above syntax the counts get inflated greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Count

```
COUNT(case when os.[STATE] = 'AL' then 1 else 0 end)
COUNT(case when os.[STATE] = 'MS' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Try using SUM

```
SUM(case when os.[STATE] = 'AL' then 1 else 0 end)
SUM(case when os.[STATE] = 'MS' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the the queries are not the same, if you wan't to get the results without a temp table you can use a derived table:

```
SELECT
    a.hacaNum as [HOV Number],
    Count(a.rstQMN) as Total,
    a.State
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            hacaNum, 
            al.rstQMN,
            os.[STATE]
        FROM
            alpha al
            LEFT OUTER JOIN foxtrot on
                foxtrot.[foxtrot_ID] = al.[foxtrot_ID]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN charche as ch on
                ch.[rstQMN] = al.[rstQMN]
                AND ch.[foxtrot_ID] = al.[foxtrot_ID]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN zulu zl on
                zl.[SHIP_MODE_ID] = al.[SHIP_MODE_ID]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN oscie os on
                os.[ADDRESS_ID] = ch.[ADDRESS_ID]
        WHERE
            hacaNum = '88' 
    ) AS a
GROUP BY
    hacaNum,
    State
Order By
    hacaNum
```

**UPDATE**

If you only want the count for some states, then you need to update the `WHERE` clause conditions:

```
        WHERE
            hacaNum = '88' 
            AND os.STATE in ('AL', 'MS')
```

Note that the `COUNT()` aggregate function counts any non-null value when an expression is given, so with `COUNT(case when os.[STATE] = 'AL' then 1 else 0 end)` the result is count all rows that are not null (1 and 0 are both not null).  The expression works using the `SUM()` aggregate function instead, but it is more efficient to discard the unwanted records before counting them, hence the suggestion to add the condition on the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: That provides an overall count - (and I did not make it clear in my OP, sorry) I need a way of getting a count for certain states such as MS and Alabam.  When I add in the case statements the counts become skewed again.